# CSV File in a FOR Loop returns "url must be a string" error

Tags: csv, automated-tests, robotframework, ui-automation

I am trying to craft a Robot Framework test that will iterate through different sites and login to them. There are two different kinds of login procedures and I've written up login steps for each. Those are stored as keywords. But I'm running in the URLs through a CSV file. The file contains the URL, and the "login_type", A or B. I want to iterate this through a FOR loop, to where I just have to call the file at runtime and the CSV file will take care of the rest.

But I am getting an error message that says "'url' must be a string." I'm not sure if my problem is the CSV file or my loop structure is wrong. Here is my code:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation       Store URLs in CSV and identify login type
Library             Zoomba.GUILibrary
Library             Process
Library             CSVLibrary
Library             Collections
Resource            ../resource.robot
Suite Teardown      Close All Browsers

*** Variables ***
${browser}          chrome
${url}              https://example1.edu
${CSV_FILE}         C:/CSV.csv

*** Test Cases ***
Example Test
    ${urls}    Read Csv File To List  ${CSV_FILE}
    FOR    ${url}    IN    @{urls}
        Open Browser    ${url}    ${browser}
        ${login_type}    Get CSV Data    ${url}    login_type
        Run Keyword If    '${login_type}' == 'TYPE A'    A Login <--stored keyword
        Run Keyword If    '${login_type}' == 'TYPE B'    B Login <--stored keyword
        Log To Console  ${url} verified.
    END
```

Here is the CSV file I'm using.
[image: CSV]

What am I doing wrong here? Can anybody answer this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to debug your test by logging the values. For example, after `${urls}    Read Csv File To List  ${CSV_FILE}` you could have a `Log Many    ${urls}`.

Then check why `${url}` is not really a string. You could also try to force it to be a string by quoting, `'${url}'` or `"${url}"`.